# Can the Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz (a.k.a. Massart) inequality be extended to two empirical distributions?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Can the [Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz (a.k.a. Massart)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality) inequality

$$
\Pr\left( \sup |\hat F_n(x) - F(x)| > \lambda \right) \le 2\exp(-2n\lambda^2)
$$

where $\hat F_n(x)$ is the empirical distribution function of the sample $X$ from the distribution $F$, be extended to comparing two empirical distributions coming $\hat F_n,\hat G_n$ coming from equally-sized samples $X,Y$ from the same distribution? What is the $ \Pr\left( \sup |\hat F_n(x) - \hat G_n(x)| > \lambda \right) $ ?

Comment: Maybe it's too early for me but can't we deduce from $sup|\hat{F}_n(x) - F(x)| < \lambda$ and $sup|\hat{G}_n(x) - F(x)| < \lambda$ that $$sup|\hat{F}_n(x) - \hat{G}_n(x)| < 2\lambda$$

Comment: Adding the maximum errors together works, but is too conservative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the DKW inequality is essentially an inversion of the one sample Kolmogorov Smirnoff test. A two-sample version exists for it too where the primary difference is the scaling of the constant. So yes, you could invert this test too.

$$
D>c(\alpha)\sqrt{\frac{n + m}{n m}}
$$

Here's a paper describing the process in detail: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.5356.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test